# How to customise UISlider height

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uislider

I have project in which have to customise `UISlider` element.
I wondering if someone knows how to change, or is it possible to change height of `UISlide` bar line.

**I tried something like this but don't work:**

```
let customBounds = CGRect(origin: bounds.origin, 
                          size: CGSize(width: bounds.size.width, height: 15.0))
feedbackSlider.trackRectForBounds(customBounds)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 24):

i hope that you want edit it in storyboard, and only the line size, use it in your custom UISlider

```
class CustomSlide: UISlider {

     @IBInspectable var trackHeight: CGFloat = 2

     override func trackRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
         //set your bounds here
         return CGRect(origin: bounds.origin, size: CGSizeMake(bounds.width, trackHeight))



       }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Overriding `trackRect` is a way to go, however if you're using additional `UISlider`'s views like `minimumValueImage, maximumValueImage` you would also need to take their bound into account, otherwise they will overlap with slider’s track. As a shortcut you can simply use `super`'s func:

***Fixed version.***

**Swift 3+**

```
 @IBDesignable
    class CustomSlider: UISlider {
       /// custom slider track height
       @IBInspectable var trackHeight: CGFloat = 3

       override func trackRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
           // Use properly calculated rect
           var newRect = super.trackRect(forBounds: bounds)
           newRect.size.height = trackHeight
           return newRect
       }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can override a method in you custom slider

For Objective-C

```
- (CGRect)trackRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30);//change it to any size you want
    return rect;
}
```

For Swift

```
override func trackRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    var rect:CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30)
    return rect
}
```

Comment: when i use this code, the height of the slider successfully changes.  but when the slider gets to the end, the rounded corner 'flashes' square.  it seems this code is not accounting for the rounded corner at the end of a slider.  any idea how to do that?

Comment: same here. Any fix for that?

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 3**

```
class MySlide: UISlider {

    @IBInspectable var height: CGFloat = 2        
    override func trackRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(origin: bounds.origin, size: CGSize(width: bounds.width, height: height))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4** version without thumbImage.

```
class CustomSlider: UISlider {
  @IBInspectable var trackHeight: CGFloat = 2

  override func trackRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return CGRect(origin: bounds.origin, size: CGSize(width: bounds.width, height: trackHeight))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the answers above have a flaw: the origin of the track rect must be offset to account for the change in height of the track, otherwise it will show up off-center. Here is the way I did it:

```
class CustomSlider: UISlider {

@IBInspectable var sliderTrackHeight : CGFloat = 2

    override func trackRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        let originalRect = super.trackRect(forBounds: bounds)
        return CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: originalRect.origin.x, y: originalRect.origin.y + (sliderTrackHeight / 2)), size: CGSize(width: bounds.width, height: sliderTrackHeight))
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

U can easily get it done by subclassing `UISlider`. see following code

```
class CustomUISlider : UISlider
{        
    override func trackRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    //set your bounds here
    return bounds

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to subclass the UISlider and then implement:

```
- (CGRect)trackRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
```

Just return the new CGRect here.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using `autolayout` you can set a `height` constraint on the `UISlider` in the `storyboard`. if you need to change it at runtime - create an `IBOutlet` for the constraint and modify its `.constant` value.

Comment: I think it's only changing the internal height if the slider, not the track height