# How to increase thumb in Android Slider?

Tags: nativescript

Could help me? How to increase thumb? Like this

I use

```js
<Slider value="80" />
```

[image: Sample]

I found the answer for Android. Need to create file `app/App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-nodpi/custom_thumb.xml`

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="@color/colorDekraOrange"
        android:startColor="@color/colorDekraOrange" />

    <size
        android:height="35dp"
        android:width="35dp" />

</shape>
```

and add a property `android:thumb="@drawable/custom_thumb"`

But how does this property add a Slider to nativescrip?

Thank's

Comment: Can you please provide more detail and your code so people can better help you? As is, there's not really enough detail to know what you are doing wrong

Comment: Thanks, Manoj. But how to do it in Android?

Comment: Sorry, guess I placed wrong link earlier. So You could do it with some native code, by setting a [Drawable on Thumb for Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSeekBar.html#setThumb(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) and [here](https://android--code.blogspot.com/2016/01/android-how-to-use-seekbar-drawable.html) you find how a thumb drawable may look like Or [Applying a scale / bigger thumb image for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42092907/how-to-make-uislider-default-thumb-to-be-smaller-like-the-ones-in-the-ios-contro).

Comment: In the example from your message I use the property "android:thumb="@drawable/custom_thumb" as it can be set to nativescript?

Comment: No, you have to use the `setThumb` method on the native instance (`.android`).