# Customize UISlider Height - Programmatically Created

Tags: swift, uislider

How do you create a custom height for a Slider when the slider has been created programmatically?

The answers to this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31590188/how-to-customise-uislider-height) explain how to do it when the Slide is setup with a Storyboard.  What if you aren't using a Storyboard and the slider is set up along these lines programmatically?  Thanks!

```
let slider: UISlider = {
    let slider = UISlider()
    slider.minimumValue = 1
    slider.maximumValue = 7
    slider.value = 1
    slider.maximumTrackTintColor = UIColor.red
    slider.minimumTrackTintColor = UIColor.green
    slider.thumbTintColor = UIColor.blue
    slider.isContinuous = true
    slider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return slider
}()
```

Comment: It’s the same thing, just initialize the custom subclass instead of UISlider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create a custom slider, and override `trackRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect`

```
class CustomSlider: UISlider {
   let trackHeight: CGFloat = 12 //desired track width, in points
   override func trackRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
      let track = super.trackRect(forBounds: bounds)
      return CGRect(x: track.origin.x, y: track.origin.y, width: track.width, height: trackHeight)
   }
}
```

and change your implementation to use this

```
let slider: CustomSlider = {
       let slider = CustomSlider()
       slider.minimumValue = 1
       slider.maximumValue = 7
       slider.value = 1
       slider.maximumTrackTintColor = UIColor.red
       slider.minimumTrackTintColor = UIColor.green
       slider.thumbTintColor = UIColor.blue
       slider.isContinuous = true
       slider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       return slider
   }()
```